# Python Pandas Question: Index / Match with Missing Values + Duplicates + Everything In Between

Tags: python

Basically, I have smaller table of assets purchased this year and a table of assets the company holds. I want to be able to get the value of certain symbols from the table of assets the company holds and merge into the assets purchased dataset. I want to use the CUSIP. If there is a CUSIP in the assets purchased this year that is blank, this code can return blank or NaN. If there are duplicate CUSIPS in the Holdings dataset, then return the first value. I have tried 4 different ways of merging these tables now without much luck. I run into a memory error for some reason

The equivalent excel code would be:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(asset_holdings!ADMIN_SYMBOLS,MATCH(asset_purchases!CUSIP_n, asset_holdings!CUSIPs, 0)),"")
```

Holdings Table

| CUSIP | SYMBOL |
| --- | --- |
| 353187EV5 | 1A |
| 74727PAY7 | 3A |
| 80413TAJ8 | FE |
| 02765UCR3 | 3G |
| 000000000 | 3G |
|  |  |
| 74727PAYA | 3E |
| 000000000 | 4E |

Purchase Table

| CUSIP | SHARES |
| --- | --- |
| 353187EV5 | 10 |
| 74727PAY7 | 67 |
| 80413TAJ8 | 35 |
| 02765UCR4 | 3666 |
| 74727PAY7 | 3613 |
|  |  |
| 74727PAYA | 13 |
| 000000000 | 14 |

Desired Result

| CUSIP | SHARES | SYMBOL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 353187EV5 | 10 | 1A |
| 74727PAY7 | 67 | 3A |
| 80413TAJ8 | 35 | FE |
| 02765UCR4 | 3666 | "" |
| 74727PAY7 | 3613 | 3A |
|  |  |  |
| 74727PAYA | 13 | 3E |
| 000000000 | 14 | 3G |

```
C:\ProgramData\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_join_indexers(left_keys, right_keys, sort, how, **kwargs)
   1140     join_func = _join_functions[how]
   1141
-> 1142     return join_func(lkey, rkey, count, **kwargs)
   1143
   1144
 
pandas\_libs\join.pyx in pandas._libs.join.left_outer_join()
 
MemoryError:
```

What I tried:

```
dfnew = dfPurchases.merge(dfHoldings[['CUSIP','SYMBOL']],how='left', on='CUSIP')
 
dfPurchases = dfPurchases.set_index('CUSIP')
dfPurchases['SYMBOL'] = dfHoldings.lookup(dfHoldings['CUSIP'], df1['SYMBOL'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4xmx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate on the question a little bit so that you can review if I have the correct understanding of your question. You want to do a [left outer join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) of purchase dataset with holdings dataset. But, since your holding data set has duplicates for CUSIP ids, It will not be a [One-to-one](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra) join.
Now you have two options:

1. Accept multiple rows for one row of the purchase dataset
2. Make CUSIP id unique in the Holdings dataset and then perform the merge

First way:

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.read_csv('purchase.csv')
right = pd.read_csv('holdings.csv')

result = pd.merge(left, right, on="CUSIP", how='left')
print(result)
```

But, As per your question, the above result isn't acceptable so, We are gonna make CUSIP column unique in the right dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.read_csv('purchase.csv')
right = pd.read_csv('holdings.csv')

# By default it takes first but i have added explicitly for better understanding
right_unique = right.drop_duplicates('CUSIP', keep='first') 
result = pd.merge(left, right_unique, on="CUSIP", how='left', validate="many_to_one")
print(result)
```

Bonus: You can also explore the validation param by putting it into the first version and see the validation errors.